CSS background image in SPCK editor
I cannot get SPCK Editor to display a back-ground image in CSS
I have just started using SPCK Editor on my phone to develop a website with HTML, CSS and JS. If I put background-image: url("***.jpg") into the css for the element in question there is no background image produced. I've tried using the image url which I have been using and putting this in an img tag in the HTML, and this works - so it is not a problem with the path or the file. I've tried background-color and this works no problem. Also same HTML/CSS works on my PC in VS Code.
How do I get a background image when using SPCK Editor on my phone?
